# How should I interpret this distribution?

Tags: distributions, interpretation

I have a distribution of response times (in seconds) that I need to describe and interpret:

[image: response_time_distribution]

*The "spikes" at the 60 second intervals are the result of data collected at the minute level (rather than second level).*

For business purposes, I have to describe this distribution in terms of what my 90th percentile value is (170 sec) and what my target value (90 sec) percentile is (47%).

But, since the distribution is not normal, do mean and std dev provide any meaningful information? And what, if anything, should I say or do about the spikes?

Comment: Side comment: After ignoring/fixing/incooperating the spikes, the distribution looks like a mixture (i.e. 0.5*density_1(x) + 0.5*density_2(x)) of two gamma distributions: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution. The percentile does provide what it is: x% of the data is lower than ... and whether you talk about it or not should depend on whether you want to make such a statement or not...

Comment: With so much data you don't need to fit a standard probability distribution (especially if one of those doesn't seem consistent with the data).  A nonparametric density estimate would provide a much better fit and would involve fewer assumptions.  If you only need percentiles, just estimate those from the raw data.  You have plenty of data to do so.  (And it might just be me but I don't think I could interpret what's going on with the vertical axis using a log scale for probability density functions.)